# git reports merge conflict with no changes, empty lines (using git-subtree)

Tags: git, subtree, git-subtree

I'm testing the use of [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree) to merge a library repo into a bigger project. It seems great in principle. Sometimes when I do a "git subtree pull" I get merge conflicts like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
An inserted line from the lib repo
>>>>>>> 4d348903449ebb584ab224cb34c6038fbf6b352d
```

That's for a change that was made in the library repo, merging into a file that has not been modified locally. Or another example, where I added a line in the local project repo, but in a file that is part of the subtree being merged:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
Another inserted line
=======
>>>>>>> 4d348903449ebb584ab224cb34c6038fbf6b352d
```

Why would git report these as merge conflicts, but the region reported as the conflict is empty? Any way to prevent it?

These are easy enough to resolve, but it messes up the git-subtree workflow

Comment: Make sure your line endings are the same on all repositories (Linux, Windows, Mac)

Comment: I think that has taken place (in the second example) when locally changed file has modify date laster than the one of the merged version.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a solution to your root problem, but rather a mitigation of it. you can use
`git merge -Xignore-space-change`
 
to ignore space changes in your commits.

It's probably a problem with your line endings. you can try a `--dry-run` alternative in merge (`git merge` does not have `--dry-run` option):

`$git merge -Xignore-space-change --no-commit --no-ff $BRANCH`

to see the changes before you actually commit them.

Answer (score -3):

Use submodules to hold shared work. There is git-slave if you do a lot of work with shared and non-shared projects that need to be coordinated. Your line ending storage disparity will disappear.

Comment: Downvoted because I asked about using git-subtree, not how to use submodules. And there's no evidence this has anything to do with line endings